# How can I run npm install as part of an Octopus Deploy?

Tags: octopus-deploy

After I've deployed my nodejs website, but before I update the IIS virtual directory, I need to execute npm install from the command line.

How can I do this with Octopus Deploy's scripts feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add a [PreDeploy](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/custom-scripts#Customscripts-ScriptsinPackagesscripts-in-packages) script with the command you want to run in your [package](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/custom-scripts#Customscripts-ScriptsinPackagesscripts-in-packages) or via the [UI](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/custom-scripts#Customscripts-Scriptsinpackagestepsscripts-configured-in-steps)

Comment: I've tried using the scripts feature but it seems very difficult to run a simple command line via any of the three environments. Do you have any examples I could take a look at?

Comment: Here is an example: https://demo.octopusdeploy.com/app#/projects/phoenix/process/step/d8aa3ec7-493f-45dd-90f2-6a33777cef2e

What difficulty are you having? The script steps take a simple PowerShell script. Perhaps share some screenshots or output showing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've marked Robert's answer as the correct one as the high-level approach is the one I needed. For the record here's the PowerShell script I used-

$installDirectory = $OctopusParameters['Octopus.Action.Package.CustomInstallationDirectory']

cd $installDirectory

npm install --silent